# Insert foreach ID to other tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've tried looking for what I want, but I'm still confused about the code. my problem is like this:

I have 3 tables

```
 1. table1 (post id, field2, ...) ex. (1, ...)
 2. table2 (tag id, tag) ex. ("1, ...", "2, ...")
 3. table3 (post id, tag id) ex. ("1, 1", "1, 2")
```

so how do I enter values post id & tag id into table3?

**PHP Code:**

```
  foreach($tags as $tag){
    $query_insert_tags = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_tags (tag) VALUES ('$tag')") or die(mysql_error());
    $query_insert_tag_posts = mysql_query("...") or die(mysql_error());
  }
```

like this:

```
insert into table3 (post id, tag id) 
select post id from table1 and select tag id from table2
```

Don't know if it's true like this, and i dont know too how to put the value into the database

```
INSERT INTO table3 (post_id, tag_id)
SELECT table1.postid, table2.tagid FROM table3
JOIN table1 ON table3.postid = table1.postid
JOIN table2 ON table3.tagid = table2.tagid
```

Comment: With your SQL you are close to your aim. Which criteria is connecting table 2 and 3?

Comment: `SELECT` statements have a `JOIN` keyword, so the need to generate table2 isn't there. Also doing an SQL statement in a loop is a recipe for performance failure. Use PDO and avoid MySQL injection. Take a walk though a MySQL lesson.

Comment: Try to get last inserted id after each query store it in variable and use to insert in another query.

Comment: I combine tables to get table3 values (post id and tag id)? so i join table1 post id to table3 and table2 tag id to table3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on the MySQL level you will have to have a column that connects between table1 and table2 on one of the tables.

Best approach of doing this without that column is to keep the last insert IDs when inserting to tables 1 and 2 and than insert those to table3:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table1 ...");
$lastPostId = $mysqli->insert_id;
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table2 ...");
$lastTagId = $mysqli->insert_id;
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTON table 3 (post_id, tag_id) VALUES ({$lastPostId}, {$lastTadId})");
```

If you just want to insert into table 3 all the possible post_id and tag_id you can do the following:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (post_id, tag_id)
SELECT post_id, tag_id
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON 1=1
```